# MongoDBの検索でネストされた配列のある要素が全て登録されているデータのみを取得したいです。

Tags: mongodb

次のようなデータがあったとして、うまくskillのstudy_atが全て登録されているデータ_id:222のみをfindしたいです。

```
users = {  
  {_id: 111,
   name: "taro",
   skill:[
     {
       name: "ruby"
       study_at: "2021-11-11 00:00:00"
     },
     {
       name: "python"
       study_at: null
     }
   ]
  },
  {_id: 222,
   name: "jiro",
   skill:[
     {
       name: "ruby"
       study_at: "2021-11-12 00:00:00"
     },
     {
       name: "python"
       study_at: "2021-11-13 00:00:00"
     }
   ]
  },
  {_id: 333,
   name: "sabro",
   skill:[]
  },
}
```

以下のようにしても_id: 111も取得できてしまうので、うまくskill.study_atが全て値が入っているデータのみfindしたいです。

```
db.users.find({skill: {$all:[{ $elemMatch : { study_at: { $ne: null } } }]}} )
```

ご教授よろしくお願い致します

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'skill.study_at'`に対して、「nullではなくフィールドが存在する」条件を指定することでご要望のレコードを取得できます。

```
> db.users.find({'skill.study_at':{$ne:null, $exists:true}})
{ "_id" : 222, "name" : "jiro", "skill" : [ { "name" : "ruby", "study_at" : "2021-11-12 00:00:00" }, { "name" : "python", "study_at" : "2021-11-13 00:00:00" } ] }
```